# How can I get a true or false if 45 second ema trend is equal to 1 minute ema trend ( while trading on 1 min)?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

My current challange is that I want to know How can I get a true or false if 45 second  ema trend is equal to 1 minute ema trend ( while trading on 1 min)?

I have tried to find in documentation and other questions but no luck so far. Multiple attempts gave no luck, hope someone here knows how to compare these trends and see if they are same.

I tried to use the ema() function, as well as the security ema to reach a lower timeframe.I only want a result if they are same trend or different among both timeframes, so I can colour the chart different to show pattern.

Here is my code going forward in time, not sure how to go back.

```
study("Multi Timeframe EMA",overlay=true)
emaCurrent = ema(close,20)
ema15m = security(ticker,"15",ema(close,20))
plot(emaCurrent, color=red, title="ema current")
plot( ema15m , color=orange, title="ema 15m")
bgcolor(color=cross(emaCurrent, ema15m) ? blue : red)
```

This is where I want to put it, a star on top of the bar to indicate a certain color if they DO match red for downtrend incoming, and green for an uptrend ( short term prediction for next bar ) .

```
plot(low, "BG", s20_ema>s80ema?color.new(color.blue,60):s20_ema<s80ema?color.new(color.red,60):na, style = plot.style_columns)

plotshape(series=longCond, title='BUY', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='BUY', size=size.small) 
plotshape(series=shortCond, title='SELL', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='SELL', size=size.small)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1st - you can't use 45s resolutions. only 5, 10, 15, 30s.

2nd - ta.crossover and ta.crossunder is when the emas equals at the current bar, you can use them for long and short signals

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dcrossover
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dcrossunder

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
res = input.timeframe("30S")

emaCurrent = ta.ema(close,20)
ema1Lower = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, emaCurrent)

plot(emaCurrent, color=color.red, title="ema current")
plot(ema1Lower , color=color.orange, title="ema lower tf")

longCond = ta.crossover(emaCurrent, ema1Lower) 
shortCond = ta.crossunder(emaCurrent, ema1Lower) 

plotshape(series=longCond, title='BUY', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='BUY', size=size.small) 
plotshape(series=shortCond, title='SELL', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='SELL', size=size.small)
```

Comment: What if I was looking to see if 1 min and 15 min matched, or 5 and 30 ( my two trading times) ?